# Samba Startup Error

Tags: samba

I installed Samba but when I attempt to run samba from the desktop menu I get this error.  `*****"Invalid desktop entry file: '/usr/share/applications/system-config-samba.desktop.**"***`

Assistance would be appreciated!

Bill

Answer (score 0):

I am using samba server in home network as  mentioned below in password protected way. You can also try.

Install and Remove from the Terminal : (Using Samba Version 4.3.11)

---

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge samba
```

But, if you are having client problems, it would be more like:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge smbclient libsmbclient

sudo apt-get purge samba samba-common
sudo rm -rf /etc/samba/ /etc/default/samba
```

To install it again

```
sudo apt-get install samba
sudo apt-get install smbclient libsmbclient
```

---

How to Reinstall smb.conf in other way

```
dpkg-reconfigure samba-common
or
sudo cp -a /usr/share/samba/smb.conf /etc/samba/
```

---

Restart Ubuntu after fresh installation and add user

---

```
root@Dell-Inspiron-3521:~# sudo smbpasswd -a username (username should be without space eg "sudo smbpasswd -a alamjitsingh")
New SMB password:
Retype new SMB password:*********
Added user alamjitsingh.*********
```

---

smb.conf required settings

---

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/samba/smb.conf


[global]
 workgroup = WORKGROUP
 passdb backend = tdbsam 
 security = user
```

In authentication section turn "map to guest = bad user" off by adding  # at starting of code

```
#map to guest = bad user
```

Below line is Optional if not working

```
force user = alamjitsingh
```

At last add your personal code

```
[Shared_drive_Name]
path = /media/alamjitsingh/Shared_drive_Name (alamjitsingh is my ubuntu username)
comment = HD Share
read only = yes
available = yes
browseable = yes
writable = no
guest ok = no
public = yes
printable = no
locking = no
strict locking = no
```

---

Useful Terminal commands

```
sudo service samba reload 
sudo service samba restar
sudo service samba stop
sudo service samba start
sudo service samba status
sudo service samba force-reload
```

Or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/smbd start
sudo /etc/init.d/smbd stop
sudo /etc/init.d/smbd restart

sudo testparm

sudo service nmbd start
sudo service smbd start
```

Or (via systemctl)

```
sudo systemctl restart smbd
sudo systemctl start smbd
sudo systemctl restart nmbd
sudo systemctl start nmbd
```

Check status of required services

```
sudo service nmbd status
sudo service smbd status
sudo service smbd restart
```

To know version of samba

```
samba -V
```

---

Comment: Thank You. Now i have a mount problem. running mount -a reutrns can't resolve server name, unknpwn error.